# GitHub CLI search repos does not recognize existing repo

Tags: github, github-cli

Using `gh search` reports that there is a `test003` repo. Why does it report that the `test003` repo does not exist in the second command?

```
PS C:\> gh search repos 'user:Liturgist'

Showing 2 of 2 repositories

NAME               DESCRIPTION  VISIBILITY  UPDATED
Liturgist/test001  a test 001   public      about 1 day ago
Liturgist/test003               public      about 21 hours ago

PS C:\> gh search repos 'user:Liturgist repo:test003'
no repositories matched your search
```

Comment: Not sure, but this works: `gh search repos --owner=Liturgist --match=name test003`

Comment: @jessehouwing, many thanks. I am looking at https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-for-repositories. Can file `content` be searched using gh?

Comment: only commits for now it seems.

Comment: You may be able to use the `gh api` option and invoke the code search API: https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-code
https://docs.github.com/en/rest/search?apiVersion=2022-11-28#search-code
https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api